# Sql query not retrieving the correct results

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to retrieve records from a movie database where the Type field is equal to "HOR" (for horror) but some of the records have more than one type (HOR,COM,ADV) and my query is only returning results where the record is equal exactly to "HOR". How can I retrieve all the records that has the "HOR" type?

My query:

```
selectCommand = "SELECT Type from DVDs WHERE Type = HOR";
```

Note:

- The Type field in the database is a Short Text
- I am coding in C# using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Can you elaborate on the data and the results?  This query will most certainly *only* return records `WHERE Type = HOR`.  But this query also makes no sense, because you're querying back the exact data you already have... the Type.  It seems likely that something outside the scope of what you're showing us is wrong.

Comment: How are records with multiple types stored?  Can all three (HOR,COM,ADV) be stored in the same "cell" at the same time?

Comment: Let me say that albeit the answers below work you still have a big problem in the design of your database. Instead of using a string with multiple codes you should create a table that represent the multiple film types. In such a table (FilmCategory) you should have the primary key of the film table and a second field representing the category. You then store three records for a file whose category is HOR, COM and ADV. Now you can query for films of category HOR and ADV. Try to do this with the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your types are all in the same column like `"HOR,COM,ADV"` then just change your `=` to `LIKE` and use wildcards `%` around the search string (`HOR` in this case).

```
selectCommand = "SELECT Type from DVDs WHERE Type LIKE '%HOR%'";
```

This will search for the string `HOR` anywhere within the columns value and not just those columns whose value is exactly `HOR`.

Comment: Glad I could help! If this worked for you then please click the green checkmark to the left of the answer. =)

Answer (score 1):

While a "LIKE" match will work (and others rightfully explained it well), I would recommend considering restructuring your data. Using a text field the way you are is really not how SQL is designed to be used.

One issue is you really can't do input validation on it. Generally, you can have (and it is best-practice to have) the DB sanity-check the data you're entering. That way noone can enter something like HAR (rather than HOR) by mistake.

Second, you can't later have any option for that field that might contain one of the combinations you are looking for as a substring.

Third, depending on DB size and load you're going to put it under, it's not a very performant solution.

I'm sure there are reasons I'm forgetting, but at least for these reasons I would recommend creating a second table for associating the film with the genre, where a primary key is (filmid,genreid)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
"SELECT Type from DVDs WHERE Type LIKE '%HOR%' ";
```